# How to migrate Elasticsearch to a new server?

Tags: elasticsearch

The old server will remove, that Elasticsearch version is v6.8, the new server installed same version. Now, I'll migrate all data to the new server. Is my operation correct?

1. Old server: `elasticsearch.yml` add `path.repo`, for example

```
path.repo:["/data/backup"]
```

2. Restart Elasticsearch services
3. Old server

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -XPUT  http://192.168.50.247:9200/_snapshot/my_backup 
    -d '{ "type": "fs", "settings": 
    { "location": "/data/backup","compress": true }}'
```

4. Create backup

```
curl -XPUT http://192.168.50.247:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/news0618
```

5. Restore database(new server ip:192.168.10.49 ):

```
curl -XPOST http://192.168.10.49:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/news0618/_restore
```

Are these operations can migrate all the data?

Comment: This will only work if the `/data/backup` path is a shared volume that is mounted in both the old and the new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `fs` as a snapshot repository location then it will not work as your new instance is hosted on different host it will not have access to your old hosts file system. You need to use any shared location like volume mounts, S3 or Azure blob etc.

You should use `reindexing` rather than `snapshot and restore`. Its pretty simpler. Refer this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote) for remote reindexing:

Steps:

1. Whitelist remote host in `elasticsearch.yaml` using the `reindex.remote.whitelist` property in your new Elasticsearch instance:

   ```
   reindex.remote.whitelist: "192.168.50.247:9200"
   ```
2. Restart new Elasticsearch instance.
3. Reindexing:

   ```
   curl -X POST "http://192.168.10.49:9200/_reindex?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
     "source": {
       "remote": {
         "host": "http://192.168.50.247:9200"
       },
       "index": "source-index-name",
       "query": {
         "match_all": {}
       }
     },
     "dest": {
       "index": "dest-index-name"
     }
   }
   '
   ```

Refer this link for [reindexing many indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-reindex.html#_reindexing_many_indices)

*Warning: The destination should be configured as wanted before calling `_reindex`. Reindex does not copy the settings from the source or its associated template. Mappings, shard counts, replicas, and so on must be configured ahead of time.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks,I found a test machine to test,run this script, it looks like successful,but i in new server use "curl http://127.0.0.1/_cat/indices", i can't find the migrated index

Comment: Are you missing port number in ```URL```? As your new Elasticsearch is running on ```9200``` port your curl command should be ```curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v```

Comment: 、{
    "took": 170,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 0,
    "updated": 0,
    "created": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 0,
    "version_conflicts": 0,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
    },
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1.0,
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": []
}、

Comment: Are these strings is ok ? i use ‘curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v ’,result don't have the migrated index .

Comment: Sorry for late reply! Yes, the URL seems OK! Could you please share your ```_reindex``` curl command? As per my understanding you have created a new test machine and installed Elasticsearch onto it for testing. Please correct me if I am wrong..